# Login Vb.net with Browser

Tags: vb.net, authentication, browser

I am doing a website login and I am having problem checking if the login was successful, because I am using the completed document already. When I make the check to see if the logout button exists, the page hasn't finished loading. 
Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub FutureButton2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FutureButton2.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = ("") Or
            TextBox2.Text = ("") Or
            TextBox3.Text = ("") Or
            TextBox4.Text = ("") Or
            TextBox5.Text = ("") Or
            TextBox6.Text = ("") Then
            MsgBox("some information is Missing please Fill all The Boxes")

        Else

            WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://combatarms.nexon.net/Support/UserAbuse.aspx")
            Form2.Show()

        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub WebBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted


        Dim Username, Password As String
        Username = TextBox1.Text
        Password = TextBox2.Text
        Form2.FutureProgressBar1.Progress = 10
        On Error Resume Next
        WebBrowser1.Document.All("userID").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
        Form2.FutureProgressBar1.Progress = 20
        WebBrowser1.Document.All("password").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)
        Form2.FutureProgressBar1.Progress = 30
        WebBrowser1.Document.All("gnt_login_submit").InvokeMember("click")
        Form2.FutureProgressBar1.Progress = 40

        If WebBrowser1.StatusText = ("Done") Then

            If (WebBrowser1.Document.All("btnLogin") Is Nothing) Then 
        msgbox("Works") 
          else  
         MsgBox("wrong")

I have worked on it for days. The login is working but I can't get it to verify it.

Thanks for the help!
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

use this one:

```
Do While wb.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
    Application.DoEvents()

Loop
```

Comment: i think you are not getting my point ... after the login , The function does not allow the page to fully load

Comment: you can wait till the page finish with Do While :)